# Trying to create a game in Xcode using c++ but failed to load image

Tags: c++

I was trying to create a board game with c++ in Xcode, but when I tried to load the image I could not get it through. I've attempted several solutions but still could not get it to work. Here's the code:

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>


#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1024
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 1024
int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 400), "FiveInARow");
    
    sf::Texture t1;
    if (!t1.loadFromFile("/Macintosh HD/Users/arthurchao/Desktop/SFML/Final/Final/Assets/Board.png")){
        std::cout<<"Could not load stones' textures!";
        return 0;
    };
    sf::Sprite blackStoneSprite;
    blackStoneSprite.setTexture(t1);
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        //handle input/events
        sf::Event event;
        
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            switch(event.type){
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    
                    break;
            }
        }
        //update game logic
        
        window.clear();
        
        window.draw(blackStoneSprite);
        
        window.display();
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error message:

```
Failed to load image "/Macintosh HD/Users/arthurchao/Desktop/SFML/Final/Final/Assets/Board.png". Reason: Unable to open file
Could not load stones' textures! Program ended with exit code: 0
```

At this point, I was completely lost as to what I was doing. I followed several tutorials on Youtube and addressed the issues I encountered one by one, so I am not sure whether it is because of the directory that causes the problem or?

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `ls -al '/Macintosh HD/Users/arthurchao/Desktop/SFML/Final/Final/Assets/Board.png'` ... is the file there at that exact location?

Comment: Yes. Or is it the way I phrase the directory that causes the problem? Like, Is /Macintosh HD/ necessary?

Comment: Omg It worked! It was not necessary! HAHAHA Thank you anyways. @Eljay